# How to get username and password for recently installed Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have recently installed Jenkins on private server. Now when I have rebooted the server, it is asking for username and password. But, I have not given any such credentials. I have turned disable signup to false from true, but I am not able to restart my Jenkins as it is showing service not recognized.

Answer (score 17):

If you have not set jenkins initial credential then it will be

- username: `admin`
- password: Go to your `.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`  for password.

Comment: i could not find secrets folder in .jenkins

Comment: Note in my install of windows it is under my install folder %JENKINS_HOME%\secrets\initialAdminPassword. Note also that initially this wasn't created because I had another service running on port 8080 so Jenkins failed to start. I had to change the port in the jenkins.xml for Jenkins to start properly and create the secrets folder.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Ubuntu, you can find initialAdminPassword using `sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

Answer (score 1):

For all of you (like me) with jenkins.war under:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/
```

but not:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

You have to start your jenkins server and then execute

```
sudo more /var/log/jenkins.log
```

you will see something like

```
*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

64876418716348764921649873214
```

That's your password for user 'admin'.